# Proof of travel insurance via credit card

Tags: international-travel, insurance, tours

I've booked a tour with the company Intrepid. They are asking for the policy number and proof of my travel insurance. I have travel insurance (including cancellation/interruption and accidents) through my credit card.

Here are some excerpts from the insurance policy:

> When you pay for your air, bus, train or cruise transportation with your card, you are eligible to receive accidental death or dismemberment coverage of up to $1,000,000.
> ...
> If your trip is cancelled or cut short by sickness, severe weather and other covered situations, you can be reimbursed up to $10,000 per person and $20,000 per trip for your pre-paid, non-refundable travel expenses, including passenger fares, tours, and hotels.

I spoke to the tour company's help desk, and they said I needed to ask my credit card company which insurance company underwrites the policy.

I spoke to the credit card company's help desk, and they had no idea.

Any advice?

Comment: Your credit cardholder agreement should specify the underwriter somewhere. Often there's an addendum or something for the travel insurance parts, so check there.

Comment: Also, read the policies carefully: many group tours require you to have insurance which will cover emergency evacuation, which is a benefit not provided by most credit card travel insurances. But, if this isn't a problem for your situation, great!

Comment: To add to @GregHewgill's comment: the extra insurance coverage is usually presented in a separate brochure or booklet. Look for it in the desk next to your cardholder agreement. If you don't have it, the card issuer can supply you another copy.

Comment: I agree with mlc, your credit card insurance probably don't cover what Intrepid requires.

Comment: The fact that your credit card company has "no idea" who actually offers this policy is not reassuring to the idea of ever claiming on it.

Comment: Which credit card company? @DavidSupportsMonica “…in the desk next to your cardholder agreement”? Is that a euphemism for “in the waste bin”, which is where most people put it without even reading it, I imagine :-)

Comment: @Traveller No, it wasn't a euphemism for the bin. Some people (ahem) keep that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between getting reminbursement in the case of travel plans going wrong, and proper travel insurance. Please see [Is credit card travel insurance any good?](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/money-mentor/article/credit-card-travel-insurance/)

> Some rewards credit cards offer travel insurance. However, your credit card is unlikely to give you all the cover you need as full medical insurance is not included.
>
> First, it’s important to establish what is meant by travel insurance.
>
> If you mean getting a refund if the trip is cancelled or goes wrong, then yes. Credit card providers are bound by strict consumer laws set out in Section 75 of the Consumer Credit Act, which covers purchases of £100 to £30,000.
>
> But credit card providers do not offer full travel insurance, as they do not pay out for medical issues that may arise during a trip overseas.

What don't they usually cover?

- They may not pay out in the event of lost luggage.
- They may not include features that are common in travel insurance policies, such as personal liability.
- They often do not cover medical emergency expense.
- They often do not cover theft of personal possessions.

The article goes on to say

> There is one card that offers comprehensive travel insurance, including medical cover. This the Platinum card from American Express, which comes with a fee of £575 a year.

But obviously this isn't "complimentary" travel insurance as the card attracts a fee, and is part of what that fee covers.

---

Although it includes life and serious injury compensation, please note the wording of the OP's paragraph carefully:

> up to $10,000 per person and $20,000 per trip **for your *pre-paid*, non-refundable travel expenses**.

It does not seem to be referring to out-of-pocket expenses, but loss of the holiday itself.

Comment: This is an important point. The OP has some kind of travel insurance, but the tour operator may well require different or more extensive insurance coverage than that provided by the OP's credit card. BTDT with an Antarctic cruise in 2020: although both my wife and I had some travel insurance coverage through our credit cards, we were required to purchase different and more expensive coverage to satisfy the tour operator's requirements. Given the circumstances...the tour operator was not being unreasonable to insist on the greater coverage.